# How to make the page load scrolled down to <div> when loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make sure that a specific line is visible when the user loads the page, even if that line appears many lines later in the page. In other words, when the page loads, it instantly jumps to that marked line. The line simply needs to be somewhere within the visible screen of the browser window. It is marked like this:

```
<div class="scrollhere">This line should always be visible when the page loads.</div>
```

- Only one of these appears on the whole page.
- I cannot edit the HTML marking the text, but can edit the CSS and JavaScript at the beginning of the document.
- I do not mean for just that specific line to be moved, i.e. with `position:absolute`, but that the page loads to that line.

How can I make the page load mid-way down the page, wherever a specific `<div class="scrollhere">` is found?

Comment: I do not have any control over the URL of the page, so using `#` and an anchor will not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if you can't edit the HTML at all, then you'll need to use JavaScript or jQuery. This is a function that I've used to scroll to an element.

### Javascript

This will query the DOM for all elements that have your class `scrollhere`. And we'll select just the first item in the array (to go to the first element). Then we'll use the [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView).

```
document.getElementsByClassName('scrollhere')[0].scrollIntoView()
```

### jQuery

```
/*
 * A scrollTo function that gets passed a selector (ID, class, element) & an optional offset
 *
 * @param {string}  location ('#resultsTop')
 * @param {integer} offset   (-100)
 */
function scrollTo(location, offset) {
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: ($(location).offset().top + (offset || 0) )}, "slow");
    return false;
};
```

In your case, you'd call this function as follows:

```
scrollTo('.scrollhere');
```

You could also optionally pass in an `offset`. So maybe you don't want to scroll to the top of that element. But would rather scroll to `100 pixels` above it.

```
scrollTo('.scrollhere',-100);
```

And being that you can't edit the HTML, then you'll definitely want to use a listener.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  scrollTo('.scrollhere',-100);
});
```

Comment: The OP did not tag jQuery.

Comment: @jwatts1980 and? He also didn't specify 'no jquery'. Gave it as an option.

Comment: Maybe there are others who will find this post and benefit from the jQuery answer though?

Comment: @Village I updated to use just a JS example. A simple one-liner

Comment: It's true, jQuery is pretty excellent at simple stuff like this. But it seems that JQuery should not be the default starting point for JavaScript questions where jQuery is not tagged. That said, +1 for the edited compete answer and for reminding me that JS has a `getElementsByClassName` function.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pure JavaScript example. No jQuery required.

Here is a simple example of this answer in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h1vyye9r/).

```
window.onload = function() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

    for (var i in divs) {
        if (divs[i].className.indexOf("class2") > -1) {
            //Finds top of of the element
            var top = 0;
            var obj = divs[i];

            if (obj.offsetParent) {
                do {
                    top += obj.offsetTop;
                } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
            }

            //Scroll to location
            window.scroll(0, top);

            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet may help you

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($('.class').first().offset().top)
},500);
```